# Will an 8-channel HD sound card output HD 7.1 surround sound through...?

Tags: audio, sound-card, surround-sound, micro-atx

I'm considering buying an [MSI C847MS-E33](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/C847MS-E33.html) mATX with an integrated CPU and sound card for use as a micro CD/DVD-player/HTPC. The mATX has six audio ports on the back panel, and one internal port/header. The audio ports on the back panel are:

- 1 x Optical S/PDIF (TOSLINK)
- 1 x Coaxial S/PDIF
- 1 x HDMI
- 3 x Stereo minijack (2 out, 1 in)

Question 1: Will the sound card output audio to the HDMI port? If so, will it output 7.1 sound?

Question 2: The stereo minijack ports are green, blue and red (Red is for microphone). On my desktop, blue is for line-in. Is blue for line-in on the mATX as well?

Question 3: Will the sound card output 7.1 audio through..

- Coaxial S/PDIF?
- Optical S/PDIF?

Comment: Well, 7.1 is 8-channels.

Comment: I know, but what I meant was: Will the sound card output 8-channel audio to the HDMI, to the coaxial S/PDIF and/or the optical S/PDIF?